# Can I use this type in query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SELECT_STATUS_OF_MAILREPORT]
    (@ID int, @Name varchar(15))
As 
Begin
    Select ID, NAME, CONTACT, EMAIL, SUBJECT, DISCRIPTION 
    From dbo.ProInfo
    Where ID = 45 and Name Like '%@Name%'
End
```

Comment: What makes you think you can't? Are you seeing an error message?

Comment: no when i execute this proc it not showing error msg

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Here's a handy guide to posing a good question (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  What is the error message?

Comment: So what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No...
Your where statement is using a literal to compare to name...
You need to change it to this.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SELECT_STATUS_OF_MAILREPORT](@ID int,@Name varchar(15))
As 
Begin
    Select ID,NAME, CONTACT, EMAIL, SUBJECT, DISCRIPTION 
    From dbo.ProInfo
    WHERE ID=45 and Name Like '%' + @Name + '%'
End
```

Note: for this to work, @Name can not be null...